# Pandas - Line plot skips x labels

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with Genre as index and % of men and % of women in columns.

[image]

My code to draw the plot looks like this:

```
dfPercentile.plot(figsize = (20,10))
```

But x axis does not show all the values of Genre. It shows only few like Action, Crime, Thriller like the following pic

[image]

What am i missing to show all the labels of the genre along the xaxis?

Comment: Can you paste your dataframe as text instead of using an image?

Answer (score 1):

You can print them all like this:

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(26,2)), index=[*string.ascii_lowercase])

ax=df.plot()
ax.set_xticks(list(np.arange(df.shape[0])))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)
```

Output:

[image]